# Sphere revolving around another sphere- CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a pure CSS design of a sphere revolving(orbiting) around another sphere. Like a moon orbiting the sun to be precise. The image of the earth fits in properly into the sphere of earth. But the image of moon does not fit into the sphere of moon.

The image attached might help to understand my question better
[image: Moon orbiting the Earth]

Below is my CSS script

```
    .center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
}

        .center .earth {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          background-image: url(https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/90000/velka/earth-map.jpg);
          margin: 3em auto;
          border-radius: 50%;
          background-size: 630px;
          animation: spin 30s linear alternate infinite;
          box-shadow: inset 20px 0 80px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
          color: #000;``
        }

            .center .earth .moon {
          position: absolute;
          top: calc(50% - 1px);
          left: 50%;
          width: 200px;
          height: 2px;
          transform-origin: left;
          border-radius: 50%;
          /*animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;*/
        }

        .center .earth .moon::before {
          content: url(moon.jpg);
          position: absolute;
          top: -25px;
          right: 0;
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          background: #fff;
          border-radius: 50%;
          /*animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;*/
        }

        @keyframes rotate {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

        @keyframes spin {
      100% {
        background-position: 100%;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add in your html code as well

Comment: May I suggest you turn to [SVG](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) instead? HTML, or CSS for that matter, aren't really made for the kind of behavior you are trying to achieve, they're for conveying stylized hypertext (think newspaper or magazine).

Comment: @amn Yes I would definitely look into SVG. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this change `content: "";`
to `background-image: url(moon.jpg);`
and remove `background: #fff` from classname `.center .earth .moon::before`

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
}

        .center .earth {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          background-image: url(https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/90000/velka/earth-map.jpg);
          margin: 3em auto;
          border-radius: 50%;
          background-size: 630px;
          animation: spin 30s linear alternate infinite;
          box-shadow: inset 20px 0 80px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
          color: #000;``
        }

            .center .earth .moon {
          position: absolute;
          top: calc(50% - 1px);
          left: 50%;
          width: 200px;
          height: 2px;
          transform-origin: left;
          border-radius: 50%;
          /*animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;*/
        }

        .center .earth .moon::before {
          content: "";
          background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsvjrANMGI8aBJSFbsHteVa04rcB1IjjNsbrhm8vTLflfpiG133g);
          position: absolute;
          top: -25px;
          right: 0;
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          /*animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;*/
        }

        @keyframes rotate {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

        @keyframes spin {
      100% {
        background-position: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="center">
<div class="earth">
<div class="moon">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50901006/changing-the-css-of-a-div-with-classname-using-javascript