# Changing the CSS of a div with classname using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I want to change the animation attribute of my CSS class with a JavaScript function. I have been trying various methods but none of them worked. Please find out where I am going wrong.

CSS:

```
   .center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
}

.center .earth {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/90000/velka/earth-map.jpg);
  margin: 3em auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: 630px;
  animation: spin 30s linear alternate infinite;
  box-shadow: inset 20px 0 80px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: #000;
}

.center .earth .moon {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 2px;
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;
}

.center .earth .moon::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsvjrANMGI8aBJSFbsHteVa04rcB1IjjNsbrhm8vTLflfpiG133g);
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 200px;
  top: -25px;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div className="center">
      <div className="earth">
        <div className="moon" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript function:

```
    function change() {
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('moon');
  elem.style.animation="rotate 5s linear infinite";
}
```

I have tried various methods but none of them are able to perform the modification. Looping through the object didn't help either.

Comment: `className` is not a valid HTML attribute. You probably meant to write `<div class="moon"></div>` instead.

Comment: @cfillion sorry I forgot to mention that I am working with React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elem` is an HTMLCollection of elements, not a single element, and setting the `style` property of the HTMLCollection doesn't work.

Instead, you'll want to change the style for each element individually:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('moon')).forEach(elem => {
    elem.style.animationDuration = "5s";
});
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a snippet to show that the method works/provide a reference:

```js
function change_spin_rate() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('spinner')).forEach(elem => {
    elem.style.animationDuration = "1s";
  });
}

document.getElementById("spin_change").onclick = change_spin_rate;
```

```css
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.spinner {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: spin 4s infinite linear;
}

#spin_change {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

#spin_change:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 64, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<a class="spinner"></a><a class="spinner"></a><a class="spinner"></a>

<a id="spin_change">Click me to change the spin rate for all spinners.<a>

<a class="spinner"></a><a class="spinner"></a><a class="spinner"></a>
```

Comment: I've added a snippet to demonstrate–it should work if there aren't other bugs... are you sure your `change()` function is getting called? Can you print the style rules for the modified elements in the `change()` function (`console.log(elem.style.animationDuration)`) and also check them in the web inspector (right click on one of the `.moon` elements and choose "Inspect Element" to see the associated CSS rules)? The JS style modifications should appear in the element's `style` attribute.

Comment: This is how I am calling the change function.   <button onClick={change}>
              Click me to change the speed.
            </button>

Comment: It's not clear from that comment what exactly you have in the `onClick` attribute, but it should be `onclick="change()"`. `onclick="change"` won't work, nor will the literal text `onclick={change}`. You can check if the `change()` function is executing by adding a `console.log()` to the start of the `change()` function definition and seeing if it shows up in the console.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. It gets executed. I tried just alert() and it works. I am pretty sure onClick={change} is how we call a function in React JSX. Take a look at the entire code here: https://github.com/avinashredyy/Moon-Orbiting-Earth

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements. You need to iterate through them and apply your change to each element.

```
function change() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("moon")).forEach((elem) => {
    elem.style.animation = "rotate 5s linear infinite";
  });
}
```

`document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array. You have to use `Array.from` on it before you can call `Array.prototype.forEach`.

By the way, `<div className="moon" />` should be `<div class="moon" />` unless you are writing React JSX.

Comment: This function could not modify the animation. Yes I am writing JSX.

Comment: I looked at your code: https://github.com/avinashredyy/Moon-Orbiting-Earth/blob/master/src/index.js. It should be ##onClick={this.change.bind(this)}##.

Comment: When I made this change it gave me an error saying "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Comment: Sorry. I didn’t pay attention to where you define the change function. It should be a class method like render.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function change() {
  let elems = document.getElementsByClassName("moon");
  elems.forEach(elem => elem.style.animation = "rotate 5s linear infinite");
}
```